# Jquery validation plugin Validate a input element if it is not Empty

Tags: jquery, validation

I´m trying to validate an input with the plugin before sending.
This is the context:

I have an input for URL

```
<input type"text" name="theURL" />
```

But... The user can or can not fill the input.
So, if the user does not fill it >> It is OK because it´s NOT required.
But if he fills it, then must corroborate that the value is a URL.

**If the input WAS required, I´ll solve it with:**

```
  rules: {
    theURL: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }
```

**But in this case (NOT required, but validated if the user put something) I don´t know what to do.** 
Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<form id='registerForm' name='registerForm' method='post' action=''>
    <input type "text" name="theURL" />
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#registerForm").validate({
         rules: {
             theURL: {
                 url: true
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/5RrGa/1508/)